# Android ListView items aligned on top

Tags: java, android, listview, alignment

I have an Android ListView.

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
```

Sometimes it contains only a few items, sometimes just one.

When this is the case, these few items are centered on the listview. But I want the items start from the top and not be centered.

How to do it?

Comment: please paste complete xml file and List item xml.

Comment: What if you remove this line `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`?

Comment: @juergen d  Post .java code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

above 2 lines made your listview to center of its parent.hence you got  items are centered on the listview.

Can you remove android:layout_centerVertical="true" from your code and try again?

Comment: @Nitesh Are you happy now ?? :)